# Find count of select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following select query that returns n number of records. I want to find how many records this query returns using another SQL query. How can I do this?

My select query is as follows
               select * from mytable;

Answer (score 3):

You can count the number of rows returned by a query by using the following structure:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
 <your query goes here>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your literal question is

```
select count(*) from mytable;
```

However, if you are using almost any programming environment using a library to a SQL server, there is a client function to return the number of rows which were selected—or possibly the number of rows which were transferred to the client.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to find out number of rows a query returns using another sql query.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Select count(*) as rows from (Query);

Comment: Can you please explain your one-line answer? How does it find count of the row set returned by the other query?

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand your question.
The answer in that case is 

select count(*) FROM (yourQuery)